# Web Service Design: Guarding against an unauthorized record id attack

Tags: web-services, security, primary-key

I am designing a web application (JavaScript + web service API) for use by multiple users, each with a user role, where the data is held in a shared database and shared tables.  It is vital that a user is never allowed to access data for which he has not been authorized (based on his assigned role).

I am worried about the security threat caused by the following scenario:

1. User X is an admin user for Organisation A and wants to add a user
   to Organisation A's reporting contact group.
2. Using the UI, User X first queries the web service API for a list of available users.
3. The API authenticates and authorizes User X and returns the list of
   user records which User X's role profile gives him access to.
4. However, before hitting the save button, User X injects a User ID which is not in the authorized list into the API call used for updating the contact group.

How can I effectively and efficiently secure my web service API against this kind of attack?

- Do I provide and expect database primary key Id values in my API calls and apply authorization logic for every Id involved in a specific API call?

or

- Do I instead generate a substitute key when I provide the list of authorized records and somehow map it back to the actual primary key when the save/update method is called?

Comment: I think that you should use server-side validation. It shouldn't matter if they inject any Id into the query, you should look at the query server side and ensure that this is something that they can or should perform. They should be able to send over any Id, and then you decide what should happen from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have very strict security requirements, I don't think exposing the PK ID values should be a major concern, but if it's practical, it's probably not a bad idea to abstract them away with some kind of substitution (just make sure you don't over-engineer that part, and risk introduce bugs or ID-collisions as a result).

In either case, what's important is that you repeat the authorization process before you complete a change. The simplest way to do this is probably just to repeat the call you did when getting the list of records in the first place, and getting a new list instead. Now you perform the change on some target record if and only if that target exists in this new list; the original list presented to User X is simply thrown away, and any change he has made to it will be irrelevant.